# Login page with vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I wanna create one SPA(just like one centered layout and when my user login the google contacts layout, boths from the vuetify page), but I have doubts about how to create a login page. the best way. my doubt are, create one router, and change between login and main page and in my main page another router to change inside the layout (google contacts) or the login page are one component and only after my user login i create o component (google contatcs) and inside the router?

tks

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this:

```js
new Router({
    mode: 'hash', // https://router.vuejs.org/api/#mode
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'Home',
            component: MyComponent,
            beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
                if(!isAuthenticated()) {
                    return next({name: 'login'});
                }
                return next();
            },
        },
        {
            path: '/login',
            name: 'Login',
            component: LoginComponent
        }
    ]
});
```

Then all you need is to implement `isAuthenticated()` in some way. You make sure that the `LoginComponent` has the functionality to set a token or cookie, so that you save some sort of login state.

Take a look at https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html